# C++: How to find the roots of polynomial modulus N

Tags: linear-algebra, c++, polynomials

I need to know what library, given a vector of coefficients and modulus N return the roots of polynomial modulus N. The library should support big integer. I'm coding in C++.

Comment: What do you mean by "the roots of a polynomial modulus $N$"? The general definition, which you need if you want to find $d$ roots (with multiplicity) for every degree-$d$ polynomial, involves computing extensions of finite fields. These are only defined quite implicitly, up to isomorphisms and do not have a "canonical" presentation. Is this what you need?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Given $n$ pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ we can interpolate a polynomial or in fact the coefficients of polynomial. Let $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{Z}_N$, and the same is true for the coefficients. Now Given these coefficients I need to find the roots of a polynomial mod N. Because the polynomial is indeed a polynomial ring.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Since my background is computer science and in particular security I'm not familiar with all math terms, that is why I explained in plain english.

Comment: What do you plan to do with these roots? A polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ may have less roots than its degree, exactly like it happens in $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm implementing the protocol proposed in: http://strathprints.strath.ac.uk/52407/

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In brief, we define the elements of a set as the roots of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_N$. Then we evaluate it at some $x_i$ elements to obtain $y_i$ values. Then we do some secure computations. At the end, given $x_i$ and $y'_i$  we can retrieve (some) of the original set elements. So we do interpolation first to obtain the coefficients and as the last phase we need to retieve the roots of the polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_N$. So I'm after a library to do it for me.

Comment: So at which point do you need computations in $\mathbb{Z}_N$?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In all points. The set elements (the original roots), $x_i$ and $y_i$ are all defined in the field. also the coefficients of polynomial are all in $\mathbb{Z}_N$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni   Indeed I need a library to find the roots of polynomial ring, given an array of coefficients.

Comment: @user13676 Welcome to Scicomp.SE! Maybe it would help if you edited the question to include a sample input and expected output the library should give, as well as a brief background on what you need these roots for. (The latter is often helpful in giving recommendations. You have already mentioned this a bit in a comment, but it would be good to have this explicitly stated -- not just as a link -- in the question as well.)

Comment: Cross-posted at http://mathoverflow.net/q/211307 , http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31987 , and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357737 .

Comment: @user13676: Please don't cross post. It is considered rude and disrespectful of users' time due to the duplicated effort needed to answer the question. I am going to close this question as a duplicate.